# Fixed Effects Regression Model (with entity and time fixed effects)

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model

I have run a simple linear fixed effects model to understand the relationship between exposure to hate speech and its adoption online. Model 1 is a simple entity fixed effects model with no covariates, while model two adds covariates to this. Model three includes both time and entity fixed effects.

I'm struggling to think of the logic behind the observation that the age variable becomes significant at p > 0.001 only when time fixed effects are included in the model.

[image]